# Clean Javascript marquee not working at chrome

Tags: javascript

i have a marquee element which only shows when the element is visible, in firefox working perfect, in chrome the marquee work one time and stop. any idea?

code:

```
var isRoomElement = document.getElementsByTagName('body'); 
    if (isRoomElement.length) {
        var elem = document.createElement('marquee');
        elem.id='mngLinksMenu';
        elem.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;text-shadow:1px 1px #FFFFFF;bottom:0px;padding:8px;width:100%;height:27rem;z-index:1000;white-space:nowrap;color:black;text-align:justify;';
        elem.setAttribute("scrollAmount", 15);
        elem.setAttribute("direction", 'left');
        elem.setAttribute("behavior", "scroll");
        elem.setAttribute("loop","2");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nojLm938/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marquee element is obsolete, as per the mdn docs. I would suggest looking for a different solution as browsers will no longer be making sure that this element works consistently.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

You would be better to look at css transforms and overflow hidden and animate this yourself with keyframes. This will be much more consistent for you

Comment: Here i found link for simple Marquee with CSS3: https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/kfmKa If anyone in future will find this topic :)